# Letter with trema being shown as percentage sign

Tags: java, string, byte

In my program I convert a byte stream I get as input to a String. But when the bytestream contains words with a ë, this letter is converted to a %. How do I fix this?

Thx

Comment: How are you converting the Byte stream... what character encoding is it versus what character encoding are you using to read the bytes as characters?

Comment: I just pass my bytearray to new String(byte[]). I don't explicitly specify a character encoding.

Comment: new String(byte[]) will use the platform's default character set when decoding the bytes. what character set was used to encode the byte stream?

Comment: Like most people already mentioned you are most likely working in wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

For encoding these characters,

Convert the String object to `UTF-8`, invoke the `getBytes` method and specify the appropriate encoding identifier as a parameter. The getBytes method returns an array of bytes in UTF-8 format. To create a String object from an array of non-Unicode bytes, invoke the String constructor with the encoding parameter. Refer this,

```
try {
    byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();

    String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
    System.out.println("roundTrip = " + roundTrip);
    System.out.println();
    printBytes(utf8Bytes, "utf8Bytes");
    System.out.println();
    printBytes(defaultBytes, "defaultBytes");
} 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```